# Unity Shader Graph Radial Fill

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, shader-graph

I'm trying to recreate shader that behaves like Radial Fill Image in UI.

Here's URP Unlit shader:
[image]

But there's a problem. I want to limit my output to alpha to be only either 0 or 1, because the result is grayscale which produces unwanted looks. So, Floor it is! No? Step? No? Look what it produces, that strange pink epilepsy.

Can somebody help me so this doesn't happen?

Thanks!

PS. Ok, I figured it out. It was because of the angle gradient. So I decided to use not a gradient and this shape works until it overlaps. What shape should I use to recreate Radial Fill Image effect?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I've managed to create Radial Fill Shader
[image]

Comment: Nice! Two questions regarding this: How would you add _MainTex to it and - more general - how do I edit the values without affecting all materials that have this shader?

Comment: Third question: How would you have it fill clock wise instead?